# How to add default Widget in customised Android Home Screen?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-launcher

I use `Launcher2 home screen` as the basis for customised the home screen.
I wanted to customized Android Home Screen with default Widget.

But when I use this example, I get this error:

```
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187): Problem allocating appWidgetId
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187): java.lang.SecurityException: bindGagetId appWidgetId=68 provider=ComponentInfo{com.android.protips/com.android.protips.ProtipWidget}: User 10081 does not have android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET.
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.bindAppWidgetId(IAppWidgetService.java:470)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetId(AppWidgetManager.java:337)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.addAppWidget(LauncherProvider.java:812)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.addAppWidget(LauncherProvider.java:790)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.loadFavorites(LauncherProvider.java:670)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(LauncherProvider.java:239)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherProvider.query(LauncherProvider.java:108)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:187)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:271)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$Loader$LoaderThread.loadWorkspace(LauncherModel.java:711)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$Loader$LoaderThread.loadAndBindWorkspace(LauncherModel.java:521)
09-28 12:03:13.052: ERROR/Launcher.LauncherProvider(9187):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$Loader$LoaderThread.run(LauncherModel.java:588)
```

I've already added `android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET` in my manifest, but it's still not working and my default widget is still missing.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET is not available for applications outside of system storage.

Without a full stack trace I cannot pinpoint the exact location of the error but this is what I expect is causing the problem.

```
void addAppWidget(Intent data) {
        int appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
        AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidget = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);

        if (appWidget.configure != null) {
            // Launch over to configure widget, if needed
            Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
            intent.setComponent(appWidget.configure);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

            startActivityForResultSafely(intent, REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET);
        } else {
            // Otherwise just add it
            onActivityResult(REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET, Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        }
}
```

Comment: So I can't add default widget in my HomeScreen app??

Comment: Yes you can, you just need to modify the above method in the Launcher.java

Comment: How to implement this method void addAppWidget(Intent data). Where can i get the Intent data if i want it to show the widget as default, where user shouldn't choose that widget. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also you can add favorite default app widgets, shortcuts, folders, etc by mentioning them in /res/xml/default_workspace.xml with the widgets component name and their location on workspace information, which will then be parsed and updated in the LauncherProvider, and binded accordingly.

Comment: @HandlerExploit can you suggest me how can i add default widget at home screen for launcher3 or have you any reference please share.